# Get Multiple Values in SQL Server Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have a cursor containing several columns from the row it brings back that I would like to process at once.  I notice most of the examples I've seeing on how to use cursors show them assigning a particular column from the cursor to a scalar value one at a time, then moving to the next row,

e.g.

```
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       --Do Stuff with @name scalar value, then get next row from cursor

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  
END
```

What I want to know is if it's possible to do something like the following:

```
    OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor; 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
           SET @myName = db_cursor.name;
           SET @myAge = db_cursor.age;
           SET @myFavoriteColor = db_cursor.favoriteColor;
           --Do stuff with scalar values

           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor; 
    END
```

Help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name, age, color FROM table; 
DECLARE @myName VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @myAge INT;
DECLARE @myFavoriteColor VARCHAR(40);
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

       --Do stuff with scalar values

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @myName, @myAge, @myFavoriteColor;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use @@fetch_status - this will return status from the last cursor in the current connection. Use the example below:

```
declare @sqCur cursor;
declare @data varchar(1000);
declare @i int = 0, @lastNum int, @rowNum int;
set @sqCur = cursor local static read_only for 
    select
         row_number() over (order by(select null)) as RowNum
        ,Data -- you fields
    from YourIntTable
open @cur
begin try
    fetch last from @cur into @lastNum, @data
    fetch absolute 1 from @cur into @rowNum, @data --start from the beginning and get first value 
    while @i < @lastNum
    begin
        set @i += 1

        --Do your job here
        print @data

        fetch next from @cur into @rowNum, @data
    end
end try
begin catch
    close @cur      --|
    deallocate @cur --|-remove this 3 lines if you do not throw
    ;throw          --|
end catch
close @cur
deallocate @cur
```