# is there a type definition similar to the oracle rowtype in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am developing a procedure where I need to insert all the columns of one table to another table including other calculation.

I have to fetch record by record, manipulate it and transfer it to another table.

is there a type definition similar to the oracle rowtype in mysql???

Any help like example or any link will be very helpful to me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing similar. You have to declare a single variable for each column to fetch
(http://www.mssqlforums.com/fetching-entire-row-cursor-t93078.html).

See this post for an example of how to use cursors in SQL-Server: [Get Multiple Values in SQL Server Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974981/sql-server-cursor)

EDIT: sorry Miljen Mikic, my bad - but for mysql applies the same: 
see this post: [Conversion of Oracle %ROWTYPE to MySQL](http://doc.ispirer.com/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-040.html)

> MySQL has no an equivalent of Oracle %ROWTYPE. In MySQL it is necessary to declare a variable for every column.

Comment: Question is about MySQL, not MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no ROWTYPE or the like behaviour on MySQL. Perhaps in a future, but in 2022 this feature remains not developed.
So we must continue declaring tons of variables in order to manage cursor data... :`(

[See related link on MySQL dev forum at High Level Architecture tab](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3433)