# DB2 Stored Procedures- looping through values?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, temp-tables, global-temp-tables

Okay, so I'm a novice at writing stored procedures.  I'm trying to perform a function similar to a foreach() you would see in a programming language.  Right now I have a temp table populated with the values I'd like to loop through.  I would like to (for each value in this table) execute a SQL statement based upon that value.  So, here's my pseudocode to illustrate what I'm really after here:

```
foreach(value in my temp table) {
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column_x = value
}
```

No I know nothing of stored procedures so how can I get this done?  Here's my script so far:

```
DROP TABLE SESSION.X;

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
  SESSION.X (
    TD_NAME CHAR(30)
  );

INSERT INTO
  SESSION.X
    SELECT DISTINCT
      TD_NAME
    FROM
      DBA.AFFIN_PROG_REPORT
    WHERE
      TD_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need, by example, a cursor.

See the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4975012/3428749
See the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180169(v=sql.120).aspx