# How to bind parameters on a SQL Server query cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-cursor

Oracle :

```
STR_SQL := ' SELECT ... where x = :1 and y = :2';
OPEN RS FOR STR_SQL USING VAR1, VAR2;
```

Postgres:

```
STR_SQL := ' SELECT ... where x = $1 and y = $2';
OPEN RS FOR EXECUTE STR_SQL USING VAR1, VAR2;
```

How can I do this in SQL Server? All I want is to avoid multiple execution plans

**EDIT:**

Does using a variable on the query with `@` preserve the execution plan ?

```
SET @RS  = CURSOR FOR SELECT ... where x = @MY_PROC_PARAMETER 
OPEN @RS;
FETCH NEXT FROM @RS INTO @VRESULT_VALUE;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Multiple Values in SQL Server Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974981/get-multiple-values-in-sql-server-cursor)

Comment: Why use a cursor at all, in any of those databases? SQL is a set-based language. It's faster (N times at least) and easier to use an UPDATE, INSERT or SELECT based on the results of a subquery than write a cursor

Comment: You don't need to preserve execution plans. SQL Server caches them. *Cursors* harm performance in this case as well, as SQL Server can cache the plan of the entire query while the cursor would allow only the `SELECT` part to be cached.

Comment: In any case, the duplicate shows how to declare a cursor but a proper query would perform a *lot* faster - for 1M rows it could perform 1M times faster

Answer (score 1):

Cursors don't perform well in SQL Server, or any loop for that matter, so I'd avoid those. The equivalent for binding parameters to dynamic SQL in SQL Server would be [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You can also just build out a concatenated query string and execute it:

```
declare @x int = 1
declare @y int = 2
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'select * from table where x = ' + cast(@x as varchar) + ' and y = ' + cast(@y as varchar)
print @sql
--exec @sql
```

The casting is needed on dates, numerics, and other datatypes to treat the `+` as concatenation instead of arithmetic.

But, if you really just want a fresh execution plan for your query, you can add the query hint [OPTION(RECOMPILE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017). Doing this isn't usually warranted. If you are getting bad plans, you should instead investigate *why* you are getting those. i.e. statistics, parameter sniffing, etc.

Comment: `sp_executesql` will execute a query, not create a cursor

Comment: yea but that would only execute the query, but i'd like to iterate the results for some other matters

Comment: Correct @PanagiotisKanavos but a cursor isn't needed here to simply bind parameters. I know cursors or loops perform differently in other RDMS, like Informix, but can't speak to postgres or Oracle, so figured it wasn't needed

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte *why* do you want to iterate at all? Why use a cursor? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Cursors are almost never the answer, unless the question is `how do I delete 1M rows in batches`

Comment: to make some calcs, with some bigger logic

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte if you post your sample data and expected results, we can help you. There are things like window functions in sql server that can replace cursors

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte that's not an answer. Reporting databases don't use cursors. Imagine using a loop over 1M rows to calculate a sum, and that's a *small* number of rows